# Angular CSS to SCSS - node modules still download css references

Tags: angular, visual-studio

i have built a project using .net core with Angular template in visual studio. by default it created client app with Angular 14x version and style to css. i need SCSS for my project so

so i have modified angular json  as below and manually modified all css files to scss extension

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    }
 ...
  }
```

now if add any package say for example bootstrap in package.json and npm i in still download css files to the node modules and not scss file.

was expecting to get scss version from node module but still getting css.what am i missing here

Answer (score 0):

Your modification impacts only the angular cli, so that when you use ng generate like: `ng generate component my-component`, it will generate the component using scss.

This will not impact your exisiting components.

```json
"architect": {
        "build": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
             "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
```

Here's a default configuration.

renames your file, styles.css to styles.scss and then update angular.json "styles" section.

The inlineStyleLangue only needs to be added if you need inline styles in scss also.

As for the node_modules, it is not related to this change and will not be impacted. Only your project's source code.

I hope this helps.